# Sessão não está sendo destruída com session_destroy()?

Tags: php, segurança

Eu logo na minha sessão, criei uma pagina logout.php para destruir a sessão. Até ai tudo bem eu consigo deslogar mas quando eu clico no botão voltar do navegador eu entro de novo na sessão. Como destruo a sessão?

logout.php

```
    ?>
    <script>alert("Logout efetuado com sucesso");
    window.location="http://dominio.com/area/login.php";
    </script>     


    <?php

    //header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/index.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
?>
```

acesso.php onde valido minha sessão

```
 $usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT `id_user`, `nome`, `nivel`,`id_franquia` FROM `usuario1` WHERE (`nome` = '".$usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."') LIMIT 1 ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
   ?> <script>alert("Login inválido! Tente novamente");
        window.location="http://dominio.com/area/login.php";       
   </script><?php
   //header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/login.php");
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioId'] = $resultado['id_user'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioFranquia'] = $resultado['id_franquia'];

    if($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] ==1){
        header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/admin/admin.php"); 
    }else if($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] ==2){
        header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/editor/editor.php");
    }else if($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] ==3){
        header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/usuario/usuario.php");
    }
```

pagina que sou direcionado

editor.php

```
<?php


if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
session_cache_expire(10);
session_start();

$nivel_necessario = 2;

    // Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioId']) && ($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] !=$nivel_necessario)) {
    // Destrói a sessão por segurança
    session_destroy();
    // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/login.php"); exit;
}
$logado = $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'];
?>
```

Comment: cara, isso é muito querer código pronto. É só procurar no google que você acha isso até em português!

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é uma pergunta que poderia ser resolvida com uma pesquisa rápida no google, não tendo utilidade para ajudar usuários futuros

Comment: estou votando para fechar

Comment: por que você tem um else sem ter um if? como você verifica se está logado ou não? poste todos os códigos das páginas envolvidas no processo

Comment: adicionei as páginas que utilizo

Comment: isso ocorre provavelmente por causa do voltar, quando você volta um página no navegador ele provavelmente pede para reenviar os dados do formulário que você havia enviado quando visitou aquela página, como seu navegador tem esses dados guardados ele reenvia criando assim uma nova sessão, se você ir para a página, manualmente sem usar o botão voltar provavelmente a sessão nao será iniciada

Comment: testei no firefox e chrome e mesmo assim me redirecionaram para pagina, ja no IE a sessão realmente foi destruida

Comment: Deixei aberta porque a pergunta me parece normal depois da edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal resolvi o problema com a ajuda do Rene e do Papa Charlie.
Primeiro usei o javascript indicado por Rene este código não deixa pagina voltar. Esse código tem que ser colocado em cada página que você queira proteger de acesso indevido então.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.go(1);
    </script>
```

Depois utilizei o controle de tempo na seção. Setei tempo no arquivo que faz o teste para o acesso então meu arquivo acesso.php ficou assim.

```
     if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioId'] = $resultado['id_user'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioFranquia'] = $resultado['id_franquia'];
    $_SESSION["Tempo"] = time() + 60*2;

    if($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] ==1){
        header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/admin/admin.php"); 
    }else if($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] ==2){
        header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/editor/editor.php");
    }else if($_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] ==3){
        header("Location:http://dominio.com/area/usuario/usuario.php");
    }
```

E depois texto o tempo em cada página que quero proteger. Pagina editor ficou assim.

```
    if ( isset( $_SESSION["Tempo"] ) ) { 
       if ($_SESSION["Tempo"] < time() ) { 
           session_unset();
           echo "Seu tempo Expirou!";
           //Redireciona para login
           header("Location:http://domino.com/area/login.php");
    } else {

        //Seta mais tempo 60 segundos
        $_SESSION["sessiontime"] = time() + 60;
    }
  } else { 
      session_unset();
    //Redireciona para login
```

}

Comment: i) onde esta o controle de cache que eu falei? ii) se você fizer o teste com o js desabilitado, o resultado será o mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Como ninguém respondeu até agora, vou dar uma solução que não sei se é a mais válida.

No Header do "editor.php" inserir:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.go(1);
</script>
```

Esse código não permite que o usuário volte a página.

Comment: pode não ser a melhor solução mas funcionou para mim, valeu

Answer (score 2):

Quando você clica em sair, uma nova pagina é carregada fazendo o logout do usuário.
Se ele clicar em voltar, a sessão NÃO será refeita, é apenas o cache do navegador. Se ele retornou para uma página com opções para editar o perfil - por exemplo - e submeter o formulário, quando a página for atualizada para executar a ação, irá verificar que o usuário não esta logado.

. Talvez você consiga alterar o tempo de cache para resolver

Comment: Eu verifiquei isso também mas a sessão é refeita quando vou atualizar o navegador ele não redireciona para o tela login. E ainda se tento prosseguir para proxima tela que precisa da sessão consigo normalmente. Mas vou tentar o cache como você me disse.

Comment: utilizei o controle de tempo e funcionou

Comment: Um teste que poderia ter feito e eu esqueci de mencionar, é usando modo anônimo - apenas para verificar que a sessão nunca se restaura como magica :) Que bom que resolveu, se quiser deixe como fez para poder ajudar alguém futuramente.

Comment: Estou com outro problema no mesmo sistema, depois que logo sou redirecionado para pagina editor.php e consiguo pegar as informações da session. Eu tento apartir do editor.php para ir para outra pagina não consigo enviar as variaveis da session. Se você puder me ajudar, agradeço